# How to create if statement in Terraform for LogicApps

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating LogicApps with Terraform. Logic Apps will do webhook and I would like to post text.

I would like to customize text field of Terraform code with If statement.
I would like to certain part of text to be displayed at only prod environment.
However my terraform code with pass entire if statement to LogicApps and I get payload error with LogicApps execution.

```
resource "azurerm_logic_app_action_http" "example" {
  name         = "webhook"
  logic_app_id = azurerm_logic_app_workflow.example.id
  method       = "GET"
  uri          = "http://example.com/some-webhook"
  method       = "POST"
  headers      = { "Content-Type" = "application/json" }
  body = <<-BODY
    {
        "blocks": [
            {
                "text": {
                "text": "[${var.environment_name}] == "prod" ? *This is prod alert* : *---*",
                "type": "mrkdwn"
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditions in your `BODY` as follows:

```
  body = <<-BODY
    {
        "blocks": [
            {
              "text": {
                "text": "Alert: ${var.environment_name == "prod" ? "*This is prod alert*" : "*---*"}",
                "type": "mrkdwn"
            }
    }
    BODY
```

Comment: How to add alert text before if statement? Suggestion:   "text": "Alert: " + ${var.environment_name == "prod" ? "*This is prod alert*" : "*---*"},